# How to make my 'game over' text stay on when collision is activated?

Tags: python, pygame

I making a small game with multiple falling cubes and the player(the square) has to avoid it. I manage to get the collision to work but the problem is when every time the circle and square collide it displays the text every time they collide. But I want the text to stay on when the circle and square first collide. Is there any way to do that?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import random
import math
import sys
import time

white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
gravity = 10
size =10
height = 500
width =600
varHeigth = height
ballNum = 5
eBall = []
apGame = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("AP Project")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):

  def __init__(self):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(apGame,red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))
    self.dist = 10

  def handle_keys(self):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
      if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit();
        exit()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      self.draw_rect(-1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      self.draw_rect(1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
      pygame.quit();
      exit()
    else:
      self.draw_rect(0, 0)

  def draw_rect(self, x, y):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    '''apGame.fill(black)'''
    self.rect = self.rect.move(x * self.dist, y * self.dist);
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red , self.rect)
    pygame.display.update()


  def draw(self,surface):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))
#The game over text here 
def show_go_screen():
  pygame.font.init()
  myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
  label = myfont.render("Game Over", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (300,100))

def instuct():
  pygame.font.init()
  myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 15)
  label = myfont.render("Avoid The Circles", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (250,450))

'''game_over = False'''
move_x = 300
move_y = 400
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
'''apGame.fill(black)'''
player.draw(apGame)
pygame.display.update()

for q in range(ballNum):
  x = random.randrange(0, width)
  y = random.randrange(0, varHeigth)
  eBall.append([x, y])

while True:

  apGame.fill(black)


  for i in range(len(eBall)):

    ball_rect = pygame.draw.circle(apGame, blue, eBall[i], size)


#where the code is supposed to work

if player.rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
          '''game_over = True'''
          show_go_screen()


        eBall[i][1] += 5

        if eBall[i][1] > height:

            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            eBall[i][1] = y

            x = random.randrange(0, width)
            eBall[i][0] = x

      instuct()
      player.handle_keys()
      pygame.display.flip()
      clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want functionality to only run once, you should add a check outside of that function to make sure the code within that function only runs once. Here's an example of that using your code.

```
collidedOnce = False

if player.rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
    if(collidedOnce == False):
        collidedOnce = True #This makes the code only run once since it's setting this variable to be true within the condition
        #game_over = True
        show_go_screen()


        eBall[i][1] += 5

        if eBall[i][1] > height:

            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            eBall[i][1] = y

            x = random.randrange(0, width)
            eBall[i][0] = x

        instuct()
        player.handle_keys()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
```

Hope this helps